# Como juntar Datatables com PHP em uma pesquisa com checkbox?

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, html5, jquery-datatables

Preparem-se porque o negócio é bem complexo.

Eu estou usando a biblioteca **datatables** do **Jquery** (sou bem novato nessa) para listar uma tabela do meu banco, ao listar, cada registro recebeu um **checkbox** para que eu pudesse pegar o id dos registros selecionados.

**Intenção:** salvar os selecionados como chave estrangeira em outra tabela,

**OBS: a página não deve recarregar até que todos os registros que o usuário queira marcar sejam selecionados.**

**Problema:** O **datatables** só reconhece os id que estão na aba atual, ao trocar de aba eles não são enviados para o meu PHP.

Para resolver preciso conseguir enviar todos os **IDs** selecionados em todas as abas para o **PHP**, também tentei com uma caixa de pesquisa, mas não conseguia enviar o resultado que aparecia em baixo para a DIV do lado sem dar **RELOAD** na página.

Vou deixar o link do repositório no **GitHub** para que quiser tentar: 
[Link para o GitHub](https://github.com/Akatsushiro/Pesquisa_de_Habilidades)

Não liguem para a organização nem nada demais, agradeceria se vocês focassem no problema primeiro.

---

Descobri parte de uma possível solução:

Eu estou usando **Jquery** para pegar o evento de click no **checkbox**, capturo o id e coloco em um **input** como texto.

O problema agora é tratar os ids, dar o explode neles é facil mas tirar os ids que você desmarca ainda não consegui.

Intenção: Tirar os **IDs** do **input** ao desmarcar um **checkbox**

Problema: Não sei como localizar essa string e muito menos removê-la

Para testar use o botão salvar após marcar e desmarcar um checkbox, percebe-rá que terá ids repetidos que ja não deveriam estar lá;

Vou deixar o link do repositório no **GitHub** para que quiser tentar:

[Link para o GitHub](https://github.com/Akatsushiro/Pesquisa_de_Habilidades)

Comment: Olá, para apontar que a sua pergunta foi solucionada, não edite o título para resolvido. Ao invés disso, aceite a resposta correta.

Comment: Obrigado, entrei no fórum a poucos dias, então é normal errar, mas já estou me acostumando, agradeço por avisar.

Answer (score 0):

Bem após muito sofrer por não ter experiencia com **Jquery** eu consegui usa-lo para só colocar no **input** quando o marcador for **Checked = TRUE**, quando falso eu uso o **replace** do **Javascript** para retirar o mesmo de dentro do **input**. Dessa vez vou colocar o código abaixo para quem quiser saber como:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#habilidades').DataTable()
})

$(".hab").click(function () {
    var txt = $('#test').val()
    var h = $(this).val()
    if($(this).is(':checked')){
        txt = txt + (h + '-')
    }else{
        txt = txt.replace($(this).val()+'-', '')
    }
    $('#test').val(txt)
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <title>Sistema de Busca sem Refresh</title>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="Jquery.js"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="datatables/datatables.css">
 <script type="text/javascript" src="javascriptpersonalizado.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="datatables/datatables.js"></script>
 <script type='text/javascript' href='meujavascript.js'></script>
</head>

<body>
 <form action="salvar.php" method='POST' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
  <table id="habilidades">
   <thead>
    <tr>
     <th>ID</th>
     <th>Nome</th>
     <th>Tipo</th>
     <th>Descrição</TH>
    </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
    <?php
    include "conexao.php";
    $dados = $pdo->query('SELECT * FROM lista_habilidade');
    while ($col = $dados->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
     $id = $col['id_habilidade'];
     $nome = $col['nome_habilidade'];
     $tipo = $col['tipo_habilidade'];
     $descricao = $col['descricao_habilidade'];
     echo "
     <tr>
      <td>$id</td>
      <td><input class='hab' type = 'checkbox' name='habilidade[]' onclick='teste(this)' value='$id'>$nome</td>
      <td>$tipo</td>
      <td>$descricao</td>
     </tr>
     ";
    }
    ?>
   </tbody>
  </table>
  <button type='submit'>Salvar</button>
  <div>
   <input type='text' name='habilidades' id='test'>
  </div>
 </form>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="meujavascrip.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Não estará funcionando aqui por faltar o Banco mas ainda será de utilidade, quem quiser ver funcionando estará como sempre no meu GitHub, Agradeço a todos que viram, mesmo sem obter resposta, pois sei que esse problema era bem complexo, ainda mais por lidar com bibliotecas externas.

[Link para o GitHub](https://github.com/Akatsushiro/Pesquisa_de_Habilidades)